# How to solve ' Maximum update depth exceeded' in my case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm developing an app in Ionic using React and I've got this error:

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

I have created a form to update some data calling an api request in the backend.

```
Request: put /xx/xx/update
Body Request: 
{
    "titleId": "1",
    "firstName": "Ani",  
}
Response:
{
    "title": {
        "1": "Dr"
    },
    "firstName": "Ani",
}
```

Inside the functional component MyData.tsx:

```
const MyData: React.FC = () => {

//title and firstName come from React Context, I'm using them in the whole app

 const {
    firstName,
    setFirstName,
    title,
    setTitle,
    iserror,
    setIserror,
  } = React.useContext(AuthContext);

  const history = useHistory();
  const authHeader = AuthHeader.getAuthHeader();

const updateData = () => {
    const data = {
      titleId: title,
      firstName: firstName,
    };

axios
      .put("/xx/xx/update", data, { headers: authHeader })
      .then((response) => {

        setTitle(response.data.title);
        setFirstName(response.data.firstName);
     
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setMessage(
          "Please check your data and try again"
        );
        setIserror(true);
      });
  };

return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <IonPage className="ion-page" id="main-content">
        
        <IonContent className="ion-padding">
          <h1>Change your data</h1>
          <form className="ion-padding">
            <IonItem>
              <IonLabel position="floating">Title</IonLabel>
              <IonSelect
                value={Object.keys(title)} // this row causes the problem
                onIonChange={(e) => setTitle(e.detail.value!)}
              >
                <IonSelectOption value="0"></IonSelectOption>
                <IonSelectOption value="1">Dr</IonSelectOption>
                <IonSelectOption value="2">Dr.-Ing</IonSelectOption>
                <IonSelectOption value="3">Professor</IonSelectOption>
                <IonSelectOption value="4">Prof.-Dr</IonSelectOption>
              </IonSelect>
            </IonItem>
           
            <IonItem>
              <IonLabel position="floating">Name*</IonLabel>
              <IonInput
                required
                value={firstName}
                onIonChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.detail.value!)}
              ></IonInput>
            </IonItem>
            
            <IonButton
              className="ion-margin-top"
              expand="block"
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                updateData();
                history.goBack();
              }}
            >
              Save changes
            </IonButton>
          </form>
        </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
export default MyData;
```

**value={Object.keys(title)}**  ==> I need to show the actual value of the selected field 'Title' when I open the form, that's why I need 'value' attribute, but this is causing the error.
If I remove this line of code, I can update successfully title and name. When I open the form again, title's actual value is not shown, only 'name'.

I'm really new in React/Ionic/Typescript and any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!
Ani

Comment: Could you share the rest of the component code, the definition of states like  `isError`, etc

Comment: Inside My Context:  
const [iserror, setIserror] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [title, setTitle] = useState<string>("");
 const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState<string>("");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:
Object.values(title) returns array.
Cast `Object.values(title)` to String using this trick:

```
value={"" + Object.values(title)}
```

The Ion Select Item:

```
<IonItem>
              <IonLabel position="floating">Title</IonLabel>
              <IonSelect
                value={"" + Object.values(title)}
                {...register("title")}
              >
                <IonSelectOption value="0"></IonSelectOption>
                <IonSelectOption value="1">Dr</IonSelectOption>
                <IonSelectOption value="2">Ing</IonSelectOption>
                <IonSelectOption value="3">Prof</IonSelectOption>
                <IonSelectOption value="4">Prof.Dr</IonSelectOption>
              </IonSelect>
            </IonItem>
            <IonItem>
```

Ps. I'm using React Hook Form

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your request `axios` inside a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) react hook :

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  axios
      .put("/xx/xx/update", data, { headers: authHeader })
      .then((response) => {

        setTitle(response.data.title);
        setFirstName(response.data.firstName);
     
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setMessage(
          "Please check your data and try again"
        );
        setIserror(true);
      });
  };
}, [])
```

The probleme is your axios request causes a rerender and a rerender causes a axios request and a axios request causes a rerender...

So if you wrap your axios request inside a useEffect, your request will be only made one time.

Comment: I would pass `data` in dependencies but this answer works

Comment: Hello @Melvynx. Thank you for your answer. For the moment, axios request is inside updateData(), which gets called everytime I click on 'Save Changes' button. What about updateData() ?

Comment: updateData is not the name of the component, is  a function getting called on the click of a button, containing axios request.

Comment: Can you show entire of your component with correct indent to have a better view of your problem ;)

Comment: and if you still have your problem try to add a console.trace statement on your `updateData` and wherever you set a state because here it's because your problem is due to a set of state

Comment: I updated my question, you can find the entire component there.

Comment: Thanks, I really don't now how this error happening.
But I can say your error is causes by a state update that trigered an other state an infinite time

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to figure this out since 10 am. :/ Thank you for your effort, I appreciate it. :)